# How can I remove a file named beginning with `#`?

Tags: bash, rm

I have a file named `#%2Amerge%2A#4984jjK#`.

`#` starts a comment in bash. So how can I remove the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By escaping the octothorpe(s):

```
rm -- \#badly-named-file\#1
```

Or by using strong (or weak) quotes:

```
rm -- '#badly-named-file#1'
```

Or by using wildcards (dangerous potentially; test with e. g. `ls` first):

```
rm -- ?badly-named-file?1
```

Comment: ... or quoting the filename.

Comment: or just `rm ./#badly-named-file#1`

Comment: This would do the needful: `rm \#*`

Comment: Using the `*` wildcard with `rm` is potentially dangerous and should only be done will all due caution, deliberation, and necessity.